# Can browser sync overwrite CSS file hosted on CDN on injection?

Tags: css, gulp, shopify, browser-sync

I was not to sure how to frame the question in just the post title, so here's the full story:

I'm working on a shopify theme and am a bit annoyed by the fact that I always have to save my CSS changes, switch the browser tab and hit reload to see what I've done (yes I did discover the theme gem which detects local changes and uploads them, but that doesn't give me reloading...).

So my plan was to come up with a Gulp task which does the following:

1. detects changes to scss files
2. compiled them to css
3. injects the changes using browser sync which proxies the shopify theme url to a localhost address

The trouble that I'm facing now is that shopify uploads changed assets instantly to a cdn and loads them from there when previewing a theme. Since the css is included from a different domain, I guess that browser sync doesn't recognize that file anymore and one to overwrite with the changes to inject.

So the remaining question is the following:

If my theme preview url proxied to a local address like `http://localhost:3000` loads the css file from something like `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0878/7368/t/2/assets/style.css?12713062062911383123`, can I tell browser sync in gulp to overwrite exactly that file with the changes to inject?

Hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: The injection part of browsersync works by using websockets, similar to AJAX requests meaning things (in this case styles) are updated on the page without having to refresh. The problem is you're not locally hosting your pages so unless you can figure a way to configure websocks on the remote servers in question (shopify) they cannot dynamically detect the change thus refresh your page.

Comment: very true! though I also used the proxy option from browser sync to work with css injection on a php site that ran locally.. And I kinda think that browser sync doenst necessarily need file system access to the files it's refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what you describe using the [rewriteRules](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-rewriteRules) options for Browser Sync.

```
rewriteRules: [
    {
        match: /\/\/cdn\.shopify\.com\/s\/files\/(.*)\/assets\//g,
        replace: '/assets/'
    }
],
```

This will intercept requests to `https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0878/7368/t/2/assets/style.css?12713062062911383123` and replace them with just `style.css?1271306206291138312` which depending on your local setup may or may need further tweaking.

Don't forget to set up bsFiles, proxy, serveStatic, serveStaticOptions, etc options as per your project requirements.